# Four horizontally aligned divs split into two on smaller screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive

Apologies if this has been answered before.

I have four horizontally aligned divs, each containing an img and text.

```
box box box box
```

When I reduce the screen size, I want these to split down the middle, to give me:

```
box box
box box
```

Instead of what I'm currently getting:

```
box box box
    box
```

Currently, when I reduce the screen size further, they do stack as 2x2, splitting to a vertical layout on very small screens (which they still need to do).

js fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/zyrkstnk/

Any ideas? I've messed around with &nbsp but can't get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: you can use twitter-bootstrap for this

Comment: I know, but it's for a single page in wordpress & I don't want to use bootstrap for the rest of the site.

Comment: Wrap the 2 thumbnails in a div. https://jsfiddle.net/zyrkstnk/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#homethumbs {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

.homethumb {
 width: 300px;
}
.homethumb, .wrap {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="homethumbs">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="homethumb">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
            <h2>Start here with the basics</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="homethumb">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
            <h2>Start here with the basics</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="homethumb">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
            <h2>Start here with the basics</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="homethumb">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
            <h2>Start here with the basics</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try flex!

```
#homethumbs {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-flow: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: wrap;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}

.homethumb {
      flex: 0 0 50%;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 50%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;  
}

@media (min-width: 1000px){

  .homethumb {
       flex: 0 0 25%;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 25%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;  
  }

}
```

Don't forget to put in viewport meta tag. Here is the video of this result: http://www.screencast.com/t/lYV6tFvhn9

Comment: Can you use this as part of a wordpress site easily? I'm new to web development and still trying to wrap my head around all this stuff.

Comment: Try it out! Find your stylesheet in the wordpress interface. It should be in the appearance/editor and it is called style.css. Then look for those two elements and overwrite your styles with the ones above. The viewport tag should be there already. This tag is used to detect the screen size so you can use @media above. So what that does is, if you are on the screen that is wider than 1000px do this.

Comment: Thanks, will do. Does flex not need an additional stylesheet loading (like bootstrap does)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex for the same and for smaller devices you can set each divs width to be 50% and set flex-wrap :wrap by this you can achieve 2*2 grid

check this snippet

```css
#homethumbs {
  display: flex;
}
@media (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #homethumbs {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100vw;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  .homethumb {
    width: 50vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="homethumbs">
  <div class="homethumb">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
    <h2>Start here with the basics</h2>
  </div>





  <div class="homethumb">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
    <h2>Start here with the basics</h2>
  </div>



  <div class="homethumb">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
    <h2>Start here with the basics</h2>
  </div>



  <div class="homethumb">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
    <h2>Start here with the basics</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps